# How to change text in each string in all text files c#

Tags: c#

I have code that is supposed to replace the word "simple" with the word "word" within all text files in the given directly, but I do not know what to correct in order for the code to work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Например, получаем все файлы определённого типа в заданной директории.
            string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Users/Users/Desktop/a/","*.txt");
            foreach (var filePath in fileList) // Для каждого пути файла...
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < filePath.Length; i++)
                {
                    var lines = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                    lines = lines.Replace("simple", "word");
                    File.WriteAllText(filePath, lines);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have an idea what your code should do? :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop within the foreach loop?

Comment: I think you just need to get rid of the inner for loop

Comment: I quite good know what the code is doing< i do not know how to get the title

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that your code is taking a while because of the line

```
for (int i = 0; i < filePath.Length; i++)
```

which makes the code occur for each individual character within each file. Simply remove it like so.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Users/Users/Desktop/a/","*.txt");
    foreach (var filePath in fileList) // Для каждого пути файла...
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        lines = lines.Replace("simple", "word");
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, lines);
    }
}
```

Comment: it cannot find a text file

Comment: It may be a problem with the directory.

Comment: yes, problem was in incorrect path

Comment: Coolioso, so did I help then?

Comment: i think that may be yes

Comment: but if i write ReadAllLines instead of ReadAllText, it Italic text=text.(Replace) in brackets

Comment: Sorry, what do you want to do with each line?

Answer (score 0):

Your double for loop reads "for each file, do something for **each character** in the file's path name"

I highly doubt that is what you want since you don't use the `i` variable anywhere

Comment: i need to change text in each string in all text files smth text

Comment: Assuming those innermost 3 lines work correctly, then put them within the first for loop

Comment: can you write code or you simply give suggestions ?

Comment: I want you to think about what your code is actually doing rather than just giving you an answer you can copy and paste